# unique stratified sampling in R - loop

Tags: r, for-loop, random, unique

I've been struggling myself to get a random sampling of my data in a for loop with R, but I need help. It is my first time writing a loop and doing random sampling...
Here there is a reproducible script of what I so far have.
I would like to run 5 times the loop to get different samples containing 3 random and unique observations each time.

So each iteration will give me one observation for 'virginica', one for 'setosa' and one for 'versicolor', different every time.

My problem is that the two functions that I am using (sample and duplicated) are acting one after the other and I need them to act together cause I want to have always the same final number of samples (N=3).

And a final question: how can I save the results?

Any help? Thanks in advance!

```
for(i in 1:5){                                             # Number of repetitions of the loop
  rnd.iris <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris),3,replace=FALSE),]  # Take a random sample of size 3 from a dataset "iris"; sampling without replacement
  rnd.iris <- rnd.iris[!duplicated(rnd.iris$Species),]     # Eliminate replicates (but it does it after the randomization -> wrong for my purpose)
  print(rnd.iris)
}
```

Comment: When you say "random unique observations", do you mean that if a certain row is chosen the first iteration, it shouldn't be chosen in a subsequent iteration?

Comment: with that I mean that at each iteration I want to have three different species, so they are never repeated:
'virginica' 'setosa' 'versicolor' -> Yes
'virginica' 'virginica' 'versicolor' -> No
'virginica' 'setosa' 'setosa' -> No

Comment: @A.Idigoras You're going about it the wrong way. It's much easier to split your data first and sample x rows, than to sample the entire data and check whether you accidentally sampled one from each group. See the link to the duplicate answer on how to do this.

Comment: @Heroka, the duplicate question fits for my data. Although I've noted that the result matrix does not keep the original row names: now the row names are the Species... I'll try to figure out how to change it inside my loop.

Comment: If you need the rownames, it might be easiest to convert them to a column (`df$something <- rownames(df)`)

Comment: Thank you very much @Heroka!!!
Just the last thing... How can I save the overall output?

Comment: Depends on the form, what you did whith it and what you want to do with it. Write.csv might be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, split the data. Then sampling.

```
for(i in 1:5) { 
  vi.iris <- iris[iris$Species=="virginica",]
  vi.iris <- vi.iris[sample(1:nrow(vi.iris),1,replace=FALSE),]

  se.iris <- iris[iris$Species=="setosa",]
  se.iris <- se.iris[sample(1:nrow(se.iris),1,replace=FALSE),]

  ve.iris <- iris[iris$Species=="versicolor",]
  ve.iris <- ve.iris[sample(1:nrow(ve.iris),1,replace=FALSE),]    

  rnd.iris <- do.call(rbind, list(vi.iris, se.iris, ve.iris))   
  print(rnd.iris)
}
```

Or, you can use `dplyr`.

```
rnd.iris <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% sample_n(1)
```

Comment: This is not very generalizible if there are many strata. And replacing is nog necessary when sampling 1, and has false as default.

Comment: @Heroka I agreed with you. See the `dplyr` answer.

Comment: This is what I actually wants, but as @Heroka says, I have too many strata in my data (123)...